# Find function f(a,b) where f(0,b) = 0, f(1,b) = 1 and f(a,b) = 0.5

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am in search of a formula for a problem I encountered. 
Simply stated, I am searching for a continuous formula where the following conditions apply:

I search for a continuous function

$f(a,b)$

in the domain of (a and b are always between 1 and 0, f itself, is also between 1 and 0 for given a and b

$0 <a < 1$

$0<b<1$

$0<f(a,b)<1$

with the following properties:

$f(1,b) = 1$

$f(0,b) = 0$

$f(a,1) = 1$

$f(a,0) = 0$

$f(a,a) = 0.5$

It is OK to have weird stuff happening (asymptotes, divisions by zero, etc) for the following values:

$f(0,0)$

$f(1,1)$

So, if anybody could help, that would be amazing. I am already struggling for a whole day.

Comment: you only want it to be continuous on the open square?  You don't care if it is discontinuous at the boundary (i,e, it's fine if it is discontinuous if $a$ or $b$ equals $0$ or $1$?  If so, then in the open square  just take $f(a,b)=\frac 12$.  Constant.  Define it on the boundary however you like.  If you want continuity at some boundary points, you should specify which ones.

Comment: The question should be clarified.  It is clear that there is no example which is continuous on the closed square.  If you have no continuity requirements at all on the boundary then there is no problem...but presumably you don't mean that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such continuous function.

We need
$f(0,1)=\lim_{a\to 0} f(a,1)= 1$ while on the other hand

$f(0,1)=\lim_{b\to 1} f(0,b)=0$.